# Back button when viewing full-page snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

When viewing a snippet in "Full page" mode it would be nice if you could use the browser's "Back" button to close it.

Additionally it would be nice if the iframe running the snippet was created in a way that does not add another entry to the browser's history - when pressing the back button once (with no full page snippet open) I expect to go back to the previous page instead of staying on the same page and unloading the snippet.

Comment: This is a very old question, but I still think it applies. I do not want to create a duplicate, so I'll give my +1 here. This shouldn't be too hard either, when using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Push a new state when opening the snippet in full. Remove or replace this state when closing or going back.

Comment: still actually a new problem.