# Stack Snippet fullscreen close button is invisible

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I'm running a Stack Snippet fullscreen, however the "Close" link is almost invisible. See image:
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Zoomed in:
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Could the close link have a solid background? Something like this:
[image: Screenshot of proposal]

Or even better, have a button instead of a link.

> ### P.S.
>
> I think that Stack Snippets, when run fullscreen, should have their own URL, (so you could click the back button on your browser and have it exit the snippet, and not return you back to your last page (a Bing search, for me)).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350699/close-snippet-obstructed-in-full-screen; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343317/missing-close-button-due-to-z-index-issue; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416643/close-button-when-trying-snippets-on-full-screen-might-not-be-noticable; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272348/back-button-when-viewing-full-page-snippet

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike No, I can see the Close link, but it's just **very** subtle.

Comment: That's pretty much *exactly* what [this question (#3)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416643/close-button-when-trying-snippets-on-full-screen-might-not-be-noticable) says, right?

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Yes, but that question is a year old, with no answers, and completely inactive. I was hoping to re-bring this to the communities' attention.